# DELETE no elimina multiples imagenes pero SÍ los registros

Tags: php

El siguiente código intenta eliminar varias imagenes (grande y thumbnail) de un producto con las rutas en la base de datos y guardadas en físico en el servidor.

Elimina el registro de la BD; pero no elimina las imagenes con la función unlink. ¿Alguien ve el error, o falta código? Gracias de antemano a quien responda.

```
<?php
include '../conexion.php';

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {

    $id= $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT id,img1,t1  FROM productos WHERE id ='.$id.'";
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die (mysqli_error());

    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
          $img1 = $row['img1'];
        $t1 = $row['t1'];

        @unlink('../files/'.$row['img1']);
        @unlink('../files/tn/'.$row['t1']);

    }
}
    mysqli_query($mysqli, "delete from productos where id =".$id.";");
    header("Location: ../");    
?>
```

Comment: como tienes el nombre por ejemplo de img1 y como esta tu  estructura de archivos?

Comment: ¿La ruta es correcta? ¿Los archivos son editables? ¿Tiene el usuario permiso sobre los archivos? ¿Da algún error? Bueno, aunque lo dé, no lo sabrás, al usar `@` con la función `unlink`. El eso de `@`  es una **mala práctica**, precisamente, porque nunca sabrás si el código falla ni por qué falla.